# Error: MySQL gem installation

Tags: rubygems

I am trying to install mysql gem, version: 2.7 though it gives an error:

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/gem_make.out
```

Though when I try:
 `sudo gem install mysql -- version "=2.7" --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config`

It does install mysql gem but of version 2.8.1 and with the following output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...

No definition for next_result

No definition for field_name

No definition for field_table

No definition for field_def

No definition for field_type

No definition for field_length

No definition for field_max_length

No definition for field_flags

No definition for field_decimals

No definition for time_inspect

No definition for time_to_s

No definition for time_get_year

No definition for time_get_month

No definition for time_get_day

No definition for time_get_hour

No definition for time_get_minute

No definition for time_get_second

No definition for time_get_neg

No definition for time_get_second_part

No definition for time_set_year

No definition for time_set_month

No definition for time_set_day

No definition for time_set_hour

No definition for time_set_minute

No definition for time_set_second

No definition for time_set_neg

No definition for time_set_second_part

No definition for time_equal

No definition for error_errno

No definition for error_sqlstate
```

There's some problem with the command line arguments, but I am not able to get it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rogue space in your gem install command: sudo gem install mysql --version "=2.7" --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

try:

```
sudo gem install mysql --version "=2.7" --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

I ran the command locally and `gem install mysql --version "=2.7"` installed correctly for me.